# Android app crashing when selecting load indicator in the notifications

Tags: bug, android-app

When you touch the loading spinner in the notification ribbon (on the right) when it is loading, the app just crashes on Android. Version 1.0.31.

Comment: Nope. You click on notification button (0, 2...) then it expands to all your notifications and while it is loafing touch the spinner.

Comment: Confirmed this behavior. The particular exception is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in `BaseActivity.java:266`